# Excel VBA - avoid Error 1004 writing UF ListBox Array to Sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, userform, vba

**Task**

My intention is to write back UserForm Listbox data to a sheet range in the most efficient way using the data field method.

**Basic Method (esp. using data ranges)**

AFAIK the most efficient method in order to write data to a range is using arrays. If data originate from a range it's preferrable to use data field arrays, which by default are two dimensional (**one based arrays**) and allow to 
a) get data from sheet to array or 
b) write back the array to sheet 
with one code line:

```
Dim v   ' As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ...

' a) range to array
      v = rng.Value

' b) array to range
     rng.Value = v
```

**Differences when using the ListBox data array**

ListBox data are stored in a 2dim, but **zero based** array, e.g. **ListBox1.List**

[Hint: Therefore it's possible to create items using a predefined array instead of using the commonly known Add method, BTW restricted to only 10 columns (indexed 0 to 9). ]

Despite this difference, it is possible to read in the ListBox data and write them back to sheet with the described basic method:

```
 ' aa) ListBox data to array
   v = Me.ListBox1.List

 ' bb) array to range
rng.Value = v
```

Furthermore, I remarked that by default the array columns count 10, so this won't correspond to the programmatically set ColumnCount. Therefore it's necessary to adapt the range checking the array dimensions, cf. debug protocol in the code example.

**Problem and work around**

Writing back the data field array to sheet in an one liner raises error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error) if there are items with a leading "==" string or comparable user inputs, as this can't be interpreted correctly by Excel.

My attempt to use

```
rng.Text  = v
```

instead of

```
rng.value = v
```

did fail, too, causing a 424 object needed error.

**Question**
==> Is it possible to correct the potential error items with leading "=" character **without looping** through all array items using VBA or API methods? Any Code example is welcome to replace my work around (step 3 in code)

**My Code**

My code consists of four steps
1) create a 2dim data field array (v)
2) set a target range (rng)
3) [my work around correcting each array item]
4) write data back to worksheet

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' declare variables
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dump")

  Dim s     As String             ' range address string
  Dim sTest As String             ' item test string
  Dim v     As Variant            ' data field array
  Dim rng   As Range              ' (target) range
  Dim i     As Long               ' rows counter
  Dim j     As Long               ' columns counter
  Dim R     As Long               ' number of rows
  Dim C     As Integer            ' number of columns
  Dim lbxR  As Long               ' actual number of listbox items   in data field
  Dim lbxC  As Integer            ' actual number of listbox columns in data field
' Error Handler
  On Error GoTo OOPS

' get programmatically defined listbox dimension
  R = Me.ListBox1.ListCount
  C = Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount
' clear sheet lines A2:A{r}
  ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(R, C)).value = ""
' ===============================
' 1) create 2dim data field array
' -------------------------------
  v = Me.ListBox1.List

' -------------------------------
' 2) set target range (rng)
' -------------------------------
' get actual data field dimension
  lbxR = UBound(v, 1) - LBound(v, 1) + 1    ' first dimension
  lbxC = UBound(v, 2) - LBound(v, 2) + 1    ' second dimension
  s = ws.Range("A2").Resize(lbxR, lbxC).Address
' set correconding target range
  Set rng = ws.Range(s)                           ' target range

' create short protocol - columns by default differ from user defined ColumnCount property !
  Debug.Print String(80, "-")
  Debug.Print vbNewLine & "** ListBox1 Defs            Data Field Array Dimension **"
  Debug.Print "                            [Target Range " & s & "]"
  Debug.Print String(80, "-")
  Debug.Print "   ListCount  = " & ListBox1.ListCount, "rows = " & lbxR & " = ubound(v,1)-lbound(v,1)+1 = " & UBound(v, 1) & " - " & LBound(v, 1) & " + 1 "
  Debug.Print "   ColumnCount= " & ListBox1.ColumnCount, "cols = " & lbxC & " = ubound(v,2)-lbound(v,2)+1 = " & UBound(v, 2) & " - " & LBound(v, 2) & " + 1 "
  Debug.Print String(80, "-")

' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' 3) Work around - correct leading "=", if any occurences presumed
'    (avoid error 1004 - App-defined or object-defined error)
' ----------------------------------------------------------------
' ==> Is there an alternative way? 
' For i = 0 To R - 1            ' edited thx to D.Lee 
'   For j = 0 To C - 1
'      v(i, j) = IIf(Left(Me.ListBox1.List(i, j) & "", 1) = "=", " ", "") & _
'                          Me.ListBox1.List(i, j)
'   Next j
' Next i     
' -------------------------------
' 4) write data back to worksheet
' -------------------------------
  rng.value = v

Exit Sub

' =============
' Error Handler
' =============
OOPS:
  MsgBox "ERL=" & Erl & " |Error " & Err.Number & "|" & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
         "s=" & s, vbExclamation

End Sub
```

**Tip** I recommend reading ["Arrays and Ranges in VBA" by C.Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

**Addendum to OP from Sep 17 '17(alternative solution)**

If you know for example that the first target column is text only, you can code the following statement before section [4] instead of searching for each list item starting with `=`:

```
rng.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: Basically I consider this version including step 3) as satisfactory for me. Split and Join transactions won't help in order to avoid loops. As I'm not firm in the field of API manoevers, I think them to be too risky; nevertheless I would be great to have some hints if there is a possible use for CopyMemory. The most interesting thing for me was that the array read in from ListBox1.List consists of TENcolumns in any case.

Comment: **Tip: ** For those interested generally in using OS API I recommend reading a smart solution by @Florent-B how to shift columns directly in the memory; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712110/how-to-add-a-counter-column-to-existing-matrix-in-vba/46786604#46786604

Comment: Edited a late *addendum* demonstrating a simple and efficient way to avoid loops thx to @ScottCraner :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lbound(v,1) = 0  ubound(v,1) = r-1
so, it needs to modify i and j.

```
  For i = 0 To R - 1
      For j = 0 To C - 1
         v(i, j) = IIf(Left(Me.ListBox1.List(i, j) & "", 1) = "=", " ", "") & _
                             Me.ListBox1.List(i, j)
      Next j
  Next i
```

Comment: I appreciate your helpful hint+, but my original work around was ok. Of course, you are right. I tipped the wrong digits in in a hurry. I'll edit my question :-) -- My hope, however, was to find an alternative direct way without extra loop through the array.