# How to populate combobox values from textbox text in excel vba form

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, vlookup

I have a problem in my VBA form in Excel and I'm trying to filter the value of a combobox using `VLOOKUP` from whatever I type in the textbox. How do I achieve this?

My code is:

```
Private Sub btnTemplateSearch_Click()
Dim filterInfo As Range
Set filterInfo = Worksheets("InfoDump").Range("E2:F46")
txtTemplateFilter.Text = filterInfo.Columns(2).Value

Me.cboTemplateType.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.txtTemplateFilter.Text, filterInfo,2,True)
```

Comment: You'll have to clarify your request. Do you want to filter the values that are in your `combobox` by typing a value into a textbox? Or do you want to use the value of your textbox to perform a `Vlookup` against a worksheet? I think an example of what you want to do and your expected outcome might help.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I was hoping to filter the values inside my combobox by using a word or part of the word typed inside of the textbox. Like instead of scrolling through entries in the combobox i will just type apple and the combobox will populate all items in my worksheet column that has the word apple in it.

Comment: A ComboBox can't filter.  You'll have to reduce the input list based on your filter before you load it into the ComboBox

Comment: Its supposed to look up all the entries that match a word in the textbox when i click on my command button. That way it the combobox will just load all the matching information based on the textbox text value

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of a block of code that can be used to filter the list of `ComboBox` entries. I decided to `Dim` an array variable `ListForComboBox` at the module level such that all procedures in the module can access it. It gets populated at the form's init event by calling `LoadListForComboboxArray`. You can make changes to this procedure to update the range of input values or any other changes.  The combobox's list property is set to this array.

Here's the caveat: you may want to consider tuning the below for performance. I included a textbox, and in the change event, I make a call to set the global array to a filtered version of the original array, based on textbox value. That means that the code will filter the array everytime you type a letter (so if you type "ABC", it will filter three times, creating a new array each time). You may want to assign that function to a different event (textbox exit, maybe) such that the code only fires once you leave the text box, and only once.

Let me know if you have trouble adapting the code:

```
Dim ListForCombobox() As String

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Filter(ListForCombobox, Me.TextBox1.Value)
    Debug.Print "CALLED"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    LoadListForComboboxArray
    
    Me.ComboBox1.List = ListForCombobox
End Sub

Private Sub LoadListForComboboxArray()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A11")
    
    ReDim ListForCombobox(1 To rng.Rows.Count)
    
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        ListForCombobox(i) = rng(i).Value
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print ListForCombobox(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it now. This really helped :)

Comment: Assigning range values to a datafield array needs to check for single cell (or row values). - FYI you might profit from reading  [how to speed up filling/filtering of listbox values on UserForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983374/how-to-speed-up-filling-of-listbox-values-on-userform-excel/47003993#47003993) - @basodre

Comment: @T.M. Thanks for the link. It included some interesting reading. One of the benefits of the approach that I used above is that it only needs to load the data into an array a single time, and then the filter is done in-memory. I sped up load time by using the `Transpose` function. I didn't do the first time because `Transpose` has a limit of 65,536 rows. I will note: I tested my function with max 65k rows, and the average time to filter the combobox was about 0.015 seconds per filter . Worth noting that this approach only works in 1-d arrays.