# Search via textbox to auto-update listbox entries

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I would like to implement a search function in a listbox in a userform getting a better view of the many columns and unfortunately I can't find a solution.

The optimal solution would be, if I could search in a textbox for any row content (up to 12 columns containing data like e.g. name, ID, position, organization, ...) and the listbox would automatically update itself showing all matching entries.

In **`UserForm_Initialize`** I filled the listbox as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 
With UserForm1
  .StartUpPosition = 1
  .Top = 1
  .Left = 1
End With
 
Dim last As Integer
         last = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
 
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 12
ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "30;50;200;60;30;110;110;90;50;40;50;80;60"
ListBox1.RowSource = "A2:M" & last
 
End Sub
```

I imagined the search function to **filter** the listbox depending on the input in `Textbox1`.

After long research and consideration (unfortunately I am an absolute vba amateur) the following code was created:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.TextBox1.Text = StrConv(Me.TextBox1.Text, vbProperCase)
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))
        For x = 1 To 12
            a = Len(Me.TextBox1.Text)
            If Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, x).Value, a) = Me.TextBox1.Text And Me.TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
                Me.ListBox1.AddItem ActiveSheet.Cells(i, x).Value
                For c = 1 To 12
                    Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, c) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, c + 1).Value
                Next c
            End If
        Next x
    Next i
End Sub
```

**My question**: Does anyone have a smarter / leaner solution or could maybe help to get my code working as currently I get the `runtime error '9'` on execution.

Comment: Posted a solution to your listbox question presenting an overall view how to handle your issues. - Feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark if helpful :-) FYI Related link (Array method) at [How to speed up filling of listbox values on UserForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983374/how-to-speed-up-filling-of-listbox-values-on-userform-excel/47003993#47003993) and at [Populate ListBox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528558/vba-excel-populate-listbox-with-multiple-columns/47531440#47531440)

Answer (score 0):

**ListBox display via filtering by search item**

In the original post occurs a *set* of issues, so you have to consider *several* points.

As some of them get asked frequently as pure methodical questions, this compilation might help to gain a more overall view besides.

- An important issue is that using the `.AddItem` method for each single element to be displayed,
  the listbox'es column count defaults to **10 columns** only whereas you try to display more columns
  thus raising an indexing error.
- If you stick to the repetitive `.AddItem` method,
  you may use a **workaround** to overcome the 10 columns **limitation**:
  a temporary array assignment to the list box is sufficient
  to increase the number of columns to the corresponding number of array columns.
- Furthermore and afaik it's *not* possible to clear or filter listbox data themselves,
  if they are bound by the `.RowSource` property.
  Therefore it would be necessary to *do without* `.RowSource` and to add data programmatically.
  *- Alternatively you might base `.RowSource` on a pre-filtered range (e.g. in a hidden sheet).*
- This means a further *drawback*: there's no way to display captions
  simply by setting the `.ColumnHeads` property to `True` without a set `.RowSource`. -
  That's why I chose sort of compromise by including heads as first data row in the answer below .
- Note that the `TextBox1_Change` event will/would be called a second time if you change the textbox string content to proper Case within the same procedure. Therefore you need to prevent redoubled data entries by some escape code lines.
- Furthermore it suffices to find the first occurrence of the given search item and to prevent unnecessary loops (e.g. by setting a boolean variable `found`).

The following example code demonstrates how to handle the shown issues trying to
*follow the original approach as close as possible*
(even if looping through a **range** instead of an *array* by means of VBA can be time consuming for greater data sets and your naming convention could prefer more meaningful variable names than `x` or `c`):

```
Option Explicit                 ' declaration head of Userform code module
```

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim ws as WorkSheet             ' declare data sheet as WorkSheet
    set ws = Sheet1             ' << define data sheet's Code(Name)
    With Me.ListBox1
        .Clear                                  ' remove any prior items from listbox
        .List = ws.Range("A1:M1").Value2        ' display head & provide for sufficient columns
    End With
    If Me.TextBox1.Text = "" Then Exit Sub      ' no further display, so escape
    Dim SearchText As String
    SearchText = StrConv(Me.TextBox1.Text, vbProperCase)
    If Me.TextBox1.Text <> SearchText Then      ' avoid double call of Change event
        Me.TextBox1.Text = SearchText           ' display ProperCase
        Exit Sub                                ' force 2nd call after text change
    End If
    With ws
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim lngth As Long: lngth = Len(SearchText)
            Dim x As Long
            For x = 1 To 12                         ' range columns
                Dim found As Boolean
                If Left(.Cells(i, x).Value, lngth) = SearchText Then
                    Me.ListBox1.AddItem .Cells(i, x).Value
                    Dim c As Long
                    For c = 1 To 12
                        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, c) = .Cells(i, c + 1).Value
                    Next c
                    found = True                    ' check for 1st occurrence avoiding redundant loops
                End If
                If found Then
                    found = False
                    Exit For                        ' 1st finding suffices
                End If
            Next x
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Me
  .StartUpPosition = 1
  .Top = 1
  .Left = 1
End With

With Me.ListBox1
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'assign 2-dim array to .List property
    'to overcome default column count of 10 only!!
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    .Clear
    'needed to overcome default limit of 10 columns only!
    .List = Sheet1.[A1:M1].Value2          ' only column heads (i.e. 1 row) to start with
   '.RemoveItem 1                          ' (delete eventually if no head needed at all)
    .ColumnCount = 13
    .ColumnWidths = "30;50;100;60;30;110;110;90;50;40;50;80;60"
End With
  
End Sub
```

Comment: @JanSchmidt - did you see my response? - feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark if helpful.