# Filter a listbox based on combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on filtering a listbox based on the combobox selection.
Currently my codes look something like this.

```
Private Sub OEMNumberComboBox_Change()
Dim database(1 To 100, 1 To 7)
Dim i As Integer
Dim My_range As Integer
Dim colum As Byte
On Error Resume Next
Sheet7.Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=Me.OEMNumberComboBox.Value

For i = 2 To Sheet7.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
If Sheet7.Cells(i, 3) = Me.OEMNumberComboBox Then

    My_range = My_range + 1
    For colum = 1 To 7
    database(My_range, colum) = Sheet7.Cells(i, colum)
    Next colum
End If
Next i
ListBox1.List = database
End Sub
```

and the below during the intialisation

```
Sub Available_Stocks()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim invd_sh As Worksheet
Set invd_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
Dim lr As Integer
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(invd_sh.Range("A:A"))
If lr = 1 Then lr = 2
With Me.ListBox1
   .ColumnCount = 9
   .ColumnHeads = True
   .ColumnWidths = "50,60,60,350,50,0,0,50,50"
   .RowSource = "Inventory!A2:I" & lr
End With
End Sub
```

with the above codes it does filter the range but it is not reflected on the listbox and I am not sure what is wrong with the code.
It is exact copy of the online codes but i have made a slight modification (so that it is filtering column C).

[image]

user interface/objects

[image]

---

Update

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'add column of data from spreadsheet to your userform ComboBox
OEMNumberComboBox.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C50").Value
End Sub
```

I have added the above code to populate the combobox but it sill shows one cell inside the listbox

Answer (score 3):

For demonstration purpose, let's say your worksheet looks like the below and I want to populate all cells where the value of column C is `1`

[image]

**Logic:**

1. Declare a `Variant` array.
2. Filter on column `C` with the relevant value from the combobox.
3. Loop through the `Areas` of the filtered range and populate the array.
4. Assign the array to the Listbox's `.List`.

**Code:**

Is this what you are tying? I have commented the code so that you should not have a problem understanding it. But if you do, then simply ask.

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> Set the listbox column count
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 8
    
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim itm As Variant
    
    With ws
        '~~> Get last row in column C
        lrow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Create a unique list from column C values
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To lrow
            col.Add .Range("C" & i).Value2, CStr(.Range("C" & i).Value2)
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        '~~> Add the item to combobox
        For Each itm In col
            OEMNumberComboBox.AddItem itm
        Next itm
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> If nothing selected in the combobox then exit
    If OEMNumberComboBox.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    '~~> Clear the listbox
    ListBox1.Clear
    
    Dim DataRange As Range, rngArea As Range
    Dim DataSet As Variant
    
    With ws
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        '~~> Find last row in Col C
        lrow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Filter on the relevant column
        With .Range("C1:C" & lrow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=OEMNumberComboBox.Value
            
            On Error Resume Next
            Set DataRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        
        '~~> Check if the autofilter returned any results
        If Not DataRange Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Instead of using another object, I am reusing the object
            Set DataRange = .Range("A2:G" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            '~~> Create the array
            ReDim DataSet(1 To DataRange.Areas.Count + 1, 1 To 8)
            
            j = 1
            
            '~~> Loop through the area and store in the array
            For Each rngArea In DataRange.Areas
                For i = 1 To 8
                    DataSet(j, i) = rngArea.Cells(, i).Value2
                Next i
                j = j + 1
            Next rngArea
            
            '~~> Set the listbox list
            ListBox1.List = DataSet
        End If
        
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for your code. However, I imitate everything you did but I cant get the code to work. It is showing a blank listbox.

Comment: Did you change `Set ws = Sheet1` to the relevant sheet?

Comment: yup I created a new excel file for it.

Comment: Further hint: provide for Error 1004 (no cells found) when trying to set the first dataRange to memory, suggest to surround by `On Error resume next` ... `If Err.Number = 1004 Then Err.Clear`.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/122xRi6AZssL9fW-v5QAIRhmzC982jx_M/view?usp=sharing this is the file

Comment: @HyunE You forgot to populate the combobox and set the columnwidths ;)

Comment: @T.M. Yes you are right. I will update the code

Comment: @HyunE Yes.. Now try it. It works :) BTW instead of `OEMNumberComboBox.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C50").Value` you can create a collection/dictionary and then add it to the combobox so that you do not get duplicates.

Comment: @HyunE Also you are forgetting `ListBox1.Columncount = 8`. Gimme couple of minutes. Let me show you how to create a complete example.

Comment: @HyunE I have updated the post. Now try it. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: Helpful post +:) ...FYI another flexible approach without range filter is [Multiple columns in ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65543548/multiple-columns-in-listbox-userform-vba/65551997#65551997)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi I am not sure whether there is a glitch but if the filtered cells are right above/below (two/three conseutive filtered values in a column), the listbox isnt able to show the values. It works like a charm, if the filtered values are not in a consecutive manner. Just like what you did above.

Comment: `but if the filtered cells are right above/below (two/three conseutive filtered values in a column)...` @HyunE: What do you mean? May I see a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This solution helps in looping through area rows to overcome the problem of consecutive rows being neglected from the returned list.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> If nothing selected in the combobox then exit
    If OEMNumberComboBox.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    '~~> Clear the listbox
    ListBox1.Clear
    
    Dim DataRange As Range, rngArea As Range
    Dim DataSet As Variant
    
    With ws
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        '~~> Find last row in Col C
        lrow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Filter on the relevant column
        With .Range("C1:C" & lrow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=OEMNumberComboBox.Value
            
            On Error Resume Next
            Set DataRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        
        '~~> Check if the autofilter returned any results
        If Not DataRange Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Instead of using another object, I am reusing the object
            Set DataRange = .Range("A2:G" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            '~~> HERE! get the real dimension of the range by looping through rows.
    Dim k As Integer
            For Each rngArea In DataRange.Areas
                k = k + rngArea.Rows.Count
            Next rngArea
            '~~> Create the array
            ReDim DataSet(1 To DataRange.Areas.Count + 1, 1 To 8)
            
            j = 1
            
            '~~> Loop through the area and store in the array
            For Each rngArea In DataRange.Areas
                For k = 1 To rngArea.Rows.Count
                    For i = 1 To 17
                        DataSet(j, i) = rngArea.Cells(k, i).Value2
                    Next i
                    j = j + 1
                Next k
            Next rngArea
            
            '~~> Set the listbox list
            ListBox1.List = DataSet
        End If
        
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```