# select the entire filtered rows and not just the cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cbCWorker_Change()

With Sheet3
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim filterRange As Range
        Set filterRange = .Range("A2:F" & lastRow)
    
        With filterRange
            .AutoFilter 1, lblTask.Caption
            Dim filter As Range
            Set filter = .Range("A2:F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            lbCWorker.List = Worksheets("Resource Planning_EMP").Range(filter, filter.End(xlDown)).value

        End With
    
End With
End Sub
```

The above code is only showing the first filtered cell but I want to see the entire rows containing the filtered data.

Comment: You deleted your previous question. I was posting an answer there :D

Comment: oh sorry I thought I figured it out using the above code so I deleted the previous post. sorry for the inconvienced ;;

Comment: A filtered range usually has non contiguous cells. It is not that simple to show them by doing something like  `listbox.list = rng.value`. You have to create an array and store values in the array by looping though the `areas` of the filtered range using a `For loop` and then use `ListBox1.List = MyArray`

Comment: If you undelete your previous question or update the above question with the deleted questions text then I can share a working example with you.

Comment: Hi I have just undeleted the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878743/filter-a-listbox-based-on-combobox this is the qns you referring to right?

Comment: yes. i will post an answer there. you can delete this quesiton if you want (i.e if this is similar to that)