# Filter data onto Listbox from value selection in Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, filter, combobox, listbox

I am trying to filter data from a worksheet (Name: "Input", Range: B2:J to last row) onto a list box (Name: lstbox1) and apply a filter to the list box by selecting an option from a combobox drop down (cmbFilter).

The combobox selection must equal value in column J of "Input" worksheet.

I haven't found anything that I've been able to apply to the below code. Sorry, I'm new to this.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
                                                
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
lr = Sheets("Input").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lr = 1 Then lr = 2

With Me.ListBox1
    .ColumnCount = 9
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnWidths = "30,40,150,60,60,180,50,0,80"
    .RowSource = "Input!B2:J" & lr
    
End With
```

I looked at code online and tried to modify my code above to solve my problem, but to no avail.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983374/how-to-speed-up-filling-of-listbox-values-on-userform-excel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to speed up filling of listbox values on userform excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983374/how-to-speed-up-filling-of-listbox-values-on-userform-excel)

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement this, but struggling to adapt it for my own list to be honest.

Comment: I've added the code, but unfortunately, changing selection in my cmbFilter doesn't do anything, all data is showing.

Comment: Please share the complete code and explain where each item is located. To have headers in the list box, you will have to copy the filtered rows including the headers to another range to be used with the list box. Also, share where this range will be located (a hidden sheet might be a good idea).