# ListBox Search Based on Textbox Value - Several errors depending upon search criteria

Tags: vba, combobox, listbox, runtime-error, userform

I have a ListBox (lstMaster) with 9 columns; a ComboBox (cboSearchItem) with values that represent the column headers and a TextBox (txtSearch).

The user selects a value from the cboSearchItem and enters a value in the txtSearch. For example, the user selects "PO" and enters "61" in txtSearch. The results are correct. Any PO that contains "61" populates the lstMaster.

However, even though it works, I get an error: Run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)': Could not set the List property. Type mismatch

See error line below: lstMaster.List(s, c) = Cells(sat, c + 1)

I would greatly appreciate some help.

```
**EDITED**
'***Search Multiple Orders Button***
Private Sub cmbSearchlstMaster_Click()
    Dim sat As Long
    Dim s As Long
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim deg1 As String
    Dim deg2 As String
    Dim RN As Integer

    txtShopOrdNum = "" 'clear txtShopOrdNum

    Sheets("Master").Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Setting to 'false' speeds up the macro
    If Me.txtSearch.Value = "" Then 'Condition if the textbox is blank
        MsgBox "Please enter a search value.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Search" 'vbOKOnly shows only the OK button, vbExclamation shows exclamation point icon
        txtSearch.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If cboSearchItem.Value = "" Then ' Condition if combobox is blank
        MsgBox "Please select search criteria.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, ""
        cboSearchItem.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With lstMaster 'Need to clear the listbox first
            .Clear
            .ColumnCount = 120
            .ColumnWidths = "0;0;0;100;120;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;75;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;110;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;50;40;0;0;0;0;0;0;60;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0;0;0;"
            'Must include the total ColumnCount and all ColumnWidths for the code to work. ColumnWidths = 0 do not appear in the listbox.
    End With
    
    Call Main 'Progress bar
    deg2 = txtSearch.Value
    
    Select Case cboSearchItem.Value
        Case "Shop Order"
            RN = 5 'column number
        Case "Suffix"
            RN = 4
        Case "Proposal"
            RN = 15
        Case "PO"
            RN = 24
        Case "SO"
            RN = 34
        Case "Quote"
            RN = 35
        Case "Transfer Order"
            RN = 42
        Case "Customer Name"
            RN = 93
        Case "End User Name"
            RN = 116
    End Select
    
        For sat = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, RN).End(xlUp).Row  '4 = first row of databody
        deg1 = Cells(sat, RN)
        If UCase(deg1) Like "*" & UCase(deg2) & "*" Then 'case insensitive AND searches the entire string
            lstMaster.AddItem
            For c = 0 To 119 'column indices, total columns
            'On Error Resume Next 'disabled this, no longer getting Run-Time Error on 2147352571 on the next line anymore...not sure how I fixed it.
                lstMaster.List(s, c) = Cells(sat, c + 1)
                              's = count of txtSearch.Value results
                              'c = total number of columns
                              'c + 1 = total number of columns + 1
                              'sat = first blank row
                              'deg1 = lower bound (last) value in column RN (sorting will change this)
                              'deg2 = txtSearch.Value
                              'RN = column number of cboSearchItem.Value
                Next c
            s = s + 1 'This MUST follow "Next c", this increments s for each new record added
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    lblTotalSearchResults = lstMaster.ListCount
    lblTotalOrders = Range("MASTER").Rows.Count
    
    'Debug.Print s, c, c + 1, sat, deg1, deg2, RN, lblTotalSearchResults, lblTotalOrders

End Sub 'cmbSearchlstMaster
```

Comment: Remember to always tag a language. VB.net? VBA/Excel?

Comment: I appreciate your help. I edited the comments to include "vba".

Comment: Populate listbox with an array  
[How to speed up filling of listbox values on userform excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983374/how-to-speed-up-filling-of-listbox-values-on-userform-excel)

Comment: Everything works. The listbox populates fine. I need to resolve the error issue.

Comment: I'm really still very new at this and could use the help. I've read the article that @taller suggested, but this doesn't take into account that I have two search criteria; a combo box selection + textbox value.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to fix this. I checked the formatting of the columns, and all are formatted as General. I've edited the code to show what searches error out and those that do not. Seems like there's a pattern. At first, I thought it errors out on partial matches greater than 3 characters, but that's not consistent.