# VBA - write "=>" as string in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write in a cell this string "=>".
Macro gives "error 1004".

Macro works correctly if I write "=>x" where x stands for another character.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Type a single quote in front of it otherwise it is interpreted as the start of a formula. Please provide the line of VBA code that produces the error.

Answer (score 7):

You can format it as text before entering the value:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = "=>"
End With
```

Comment: Helped me to solve an old question +1 :-) see [Avoid error 1004 writing UF ListBox array (back) to sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256010/excel-vba-avoid-error-1004-writing-uf-listbox-array-to-sheet)

Comment: Helped me. Thanks so much. I was parsing a text file and writing to a table. Some of the text contained equals signs and caused a run-time error. By formatting the range to text this solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that Excel understands `=>` as the beginning of a formula because it starts with an equal sign, and you get the error because the formula is incomplete.

If you want to force Excel to understand it as text add a single quote as first character:

```
Range("A1").Value = "'=>"
```

Excel will not show the quote `'` but it will recognize the cell content as text instead of a formula.